# IF statement in Structured text in PLCs

Tags: plc

I have a function block like this:

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK chujwamwdupe
VAR_INPUT
    en:BOOL;
    val:INT;
END_VAR
VAR_OUTPUT
    oval:INT;
END_VAR
VAR
END_VAR
```

And the code:

```
IF (en = TRUE) THEN
    oval := val;
END_IF
```

As simple as it is. Why on earth this block always executes? No matter if en is true or false it always changes oval to val.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume with PLC you mean CODESYS I tried this out with 3.5.18.0 and it seems the compiler employs variable hoisting in this case. Restructuring your code to something like this:

```
oval := val;
IF (en = TRUE) THEN
    oval := val;
END_IF
```

What you probably want is to use oval as an input output variable like this:

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK chujwamwdupe
VAR_INPUT
    en:BOOL;
    val:INT;
END_VAR
VAR_IN_OUT
    oval:INT;
END_VAR
VAR
END_VAR
```

If defined as an input output variable oval will retain its original value if en is False

If you dont want to retain its original value

You could initialize oval:

```
oval := 11; // magic number
IF (en = TRUE) THEN
    oval := val;
END_IF
```

Or you could add an else statement:

```
IF (en = TRUE) THEN
    oval := val;
ELSE
    oval := 11; // magic number
END_IF
```

Answer (score -1):

I have tested it with TwinCAT 3.1.4022 and here it works as I think it is intended.

But the FB remembers it's oval value from call to call, is this maybe why it looks like it always updates the output value?

[image: en=FALSE, and oval <> val]